# How to obtain blocks information easily?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, etherscan, blocks

I am interested in collecting blocks' information in Ethereum. For example, for each block i want to get the followings: Gas Limit, Used Gas, Gas Price, Tx fee, Number of tx, number of uncles.

I am using Etherscan API (in particular this function getBlockByNumber). The problem is that using my machine for 24 hours by now, i only got the info for 2,000 blocks (very slow way). Another issue is that i am having issues with number of requests sent (API has a limit on number of requests).

Is there an easy way to get blocks' info? I am looking for 1,000,000 blocks in general.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to get it fast from anyone if you want it free. There are paid API services:
Infura,
Alchemy,
Etherscan,
etc. etc. etc.

Free way: run an erigon node at home. And query that for whatever data you want.
https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon